# Как найти директорию с файлами страницы Virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Как узнать директорию в исходниках в Joomla с компонентом Virtumart, если нужно найти одну страницу, например меню сайта, как на сайте dallat.ru/food-menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сам компонент лежит в /components/com_virtuemart

А меню сайта может быть и от самой Joomla.
Ищите его в папке с действующим шаблоном, в том числе среди overrides.

/templates/vina_incomeup и т.д.

Либо это может быть отдельный модуль типа Megamenu - вывод которого также изменяется через overrides.

Comment: мне нужно изменить файл, в котором меню одного интернет магазина и нужно изменить картинку в блоге, я пытался через стили, но никак не получается и подумал найти исходники меню

Comment: Если бы вы выражались менее туманно, было бы проще дать ответ.
:)

Comment: нужно изменить картинку в блоке, чтобы она полностью заполняла блок, я пытался через стили, но ничего не изменяется и хочу найти html код, в котором находится блок с картинкой

Comment: В Chrome - правая кнопка, просмотреть код.
Там всё и увидите, причем прямо в консоли браузера можно поменять и html-код, и css.
Потом останется найти этот элемент среди файлов сайта.

Comment: проблема не как сделать, а проблема найти этот элемент среди файлов сайта

Comment: В Dreamweaver элементарно - поиск строки кода по всему заданному локальному сайту (директории). 
Есть и удаленные способы, в зависимости от типа соединения и клиента.